# Functions firing at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to write a function that fades X elements out in sequence and once finished run another function.

```
    function fadeOut(pro){
        $('.interactive ul li').each(function(i) {
            $(this).find('a').delay(200*(i+1)).fadeOut(200,function(){
                $('.opening-title').delay(500).fadeOut();
            });
            showTimeline(pro);
        });         
    }

    function showTimeline(pro){
        $('.timeline-container').addClass('in-view');
        console.log(pro);
    }
```

For some reason 'showTimeline()' runs at the same time and I can't understand why?

---

**Full JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    'use strict';

    function init() {

        function showPath(pro) {
            fadeOut(pro);

        }

        function fadeOut(pro) {
            $('.ul li').each(function(i) {
                $(this).find('a').delay(1200 * (i + 1)).fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $('.title').delay(500).fadeOut();
                });
            });
            showTimeline(pro);
        }

        function showTimeline(pro) {
            $('.container').addClass('in-view');
            console.log(pro);
        }

        $('.path').on('click', function() {
            showPath( $(this).attr('data-pro') );
        });


    } //end init

    init();

}); //end doc ready
```

Comment: because you are calling it in a loop

Comment: The delay probably used a setTimeout to defer the fadeout with 200ms. This also causes the showTimeline(pro) to be run first, since the defer will queue the fadeout function at the end of the stack.

Comment: showTimeline is in the each loop

Comment: I've tried it outside the loop with no luck @YounesM

Comment: Because it is not waiting until the fade is complete....

Comment: @Liam do you need function inside function?

Comment: I guess not @brk I'm just trying everything at the minute ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until all elements are faded. [Working Example](http://codepen.io/feardarkness/pen/evRjPZ?editors=1010)

But, basically just add a counter to know when all elements are faded:

```
var hiddenElements = 0;  
function fadeOut(pro){
        $('.interactive ul li').each(function(i) {
            $(this).find('a').delay(200*(i+1)).fadeOut(200,function(){
                $('.opening-title').delay(500).fadeOut();
                hiddenElements++;
                if (hiddenElements === $('.interactive ul li').length){
                  showTimeline(pro);          
                }
            });            
        });    

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `showTimeline` function in a loop. Call it this way instead ...

```
function fadeOut(pro) {
    $('.interactive ul li').each(function(i) {
        $(this).find('a').delay(200 * (i + 1)).fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('.opening-title').delay(500).fadeOut();
        });
    });
    showTimeline(pro);
}

function showTimeline(pro) {
    $('.timeline-container').addClass('in-view');
    console.log(pro);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [**when**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
var fadeOut=function(pro){
        $('.interactive ul li').each(function(i) {
            $(this).find('a').delay(200*(i+1)).fadeOut(200,function(){
                $('.opening-title').delay(500).fadeOut();
            });
            showTimeline(pro);
        });         
    }

 var showTimeline=function(pro){
        $('.timeline-container').addClass('in-view');
        console.log(pro);
    }
$.when(fadeOut()).then(showTimeline());
```

I am not able to completely test it but you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  'use strict';

  $('.path').on('click', function() {
    $.when(fadeOut($(this).attr('data-pro'))).then(showTimeline($(this).attr('data-pro')));

  });

  function fadeOut(pro) {
    $('.ul li').each(function(i) {
      $(this).find('a').delay(1200 * (i + 1)).fadeOut(200, function() {
        $('.title').delay(500).fadeOut();
      });
    });
  }

  function showTimeline(pro) {
    $('.container').addClass('in-view');
    console.log(pro);
  }
});
```

Comment: Now all the functions run on the page load @Brk, I'll post my full JS